# How to get curly braces to align properly in vim?

Tags: vim, formatting, vi

I lost my .vimrc file in a harddrive failure. I got it from somewhere on the internet, but now I can't seem to find it.

I went ahead and slightly modified this .vimrc file

https://gist.github.com/rocarvaj/2513367

but it just doesn't work the same.

Indentation works fine after methods, but the braces don't align properly

For instance:

```
int main()
{
      //code 
      }
```

In the old one it would align properly as such:

```
    int main()
    {
          //code 
    }
```

Here is my .vimrc:

http://pastebin.com/jmk3CbTL

my ~/.vim/bundle/ folder:

- ctrlp.vim
- delimitMate
- indentLine
- nerdtree
- omni
- supertab
- ultisnips

Is there anything I can add to my .vimrc file to display my code as I want?

I suspect it might be a problem with delimitMate and autocompletion

EDIT:

it seems that removing delimitMate altogether worked. I will investigate further

Comment: Stop using `smartindent`, it has issues. `autoindent` and `filetype plugin indent on` is all you need.

Comment: @DhruvaSagar I did that thanks. Works fine without delimitMate. If I put it back into my bundle folder, it screws everything up

Answer (score 1):

In your settings the value of `cinoptions` must have `}0` for `{` and `}` to align. For further info, try:

```
:help cino-}
```

**Update**

This is what I have:

```
cinoptions=>1s,e1,n0,f0,{0,}0,^0,:s,=s,ps,ts,c3,i2s,+s,(0,u0,)20,*30,gs,hs,W2s
```